# Golang - syntax error: unexpected { after top level declaration

Tags: go

I am new to Golang, and in my file that I started writing, which looks like this:

```
package controllers

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
)

type Coordinate Struct {
    Lat string `json:"lat"`
    Lng string `json:"lng"`
}

type Location Struct {
    Name string
    Country string
    CountryCode string
    Center Coordinate
    Coordinates []Coordinate
}

const baseURL = "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/lookup"
const osmIDs = "R8063578"

// ImportRegions fetches, transforms and saves geocoding data from osm as json file
func (server *Server) ImportRegions(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    res, err := http.Get(baseURL + "?osm_ids=" + osmIDs + "&format=json&polygon_geojson=1")

    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusBadRequest)
    }

    bytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)

    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusBadRequest)
    }

    var location Location

    if err := json.Unmarshal(bytes, &location); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error parsing json", err)
    }

    fmt.Println(location)
}
```

And I am receiving the following error:

> ```
> api/controllers/gecoder.go:10:24: syntax error: unexpected { after top level declaration
> api/controllers/gecoder.go:16:22: syntax error: unexpected { after top level declaration
> ```

Why do I get that error for the two types that I defined?
How should I fix this?

Comment: It would be struct not Struct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Struct` is syntactically incorrect, you want `struct` (lowercase)

```
type Coordinate struct {
[...]
```

[Structs - A Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/2)